# Code feedback and MVC understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller

I am embarrassed to admit it has taken me quite a while to grasp that model in MVC is just another class you reference for the data and logic an app needs (I hope that's right). I used to get confused, and end up putting everything into the controller file. The tutorials I'd followed didn't help by using arrays in the controller. I spent the weekend going through stackoverflow questions, and came across a project where you have two lights - only one can be on at a time. I thought this would be a good project for seeing if I've grasped the basics of MVC.

I linked up the buttons and "lights" of the view up to the controller. The buttons trigger a method - button1pressed and button2pressed. I then check if the light is on or off (set to a property), and then call the relevant method in the model file - turnLightOn or turnLightOff. It all works as I wanted it to.

I didn't have long to type it up; the methods could be more complete. I could pass in the labels and also change the background colours and states in the method call instead of doing them in the controller.

Firstly, have I got the right idea of calling the model method like this?
Am I right to alloc and init the model instance in the view did load, and 
  set the properties there?
Have I used self properly - is it needed for all references to controller
  properties?

Any feedback also greatly appreciated. I am using xcode 5 (rubbish internet connection) and objective c (until I 'get it').

Thank you for your time, and wisdom

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "modelLight.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lightOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lightTwo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lightOneState;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lightTwoState;

@property (strong, nonatomic) modelLight *model;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "modelLight.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize lightOne, lightTwo, lightOneState, lightTwoState;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Set light one state to on
    self.lightOneState = @"on";
    self.lightOne.text = @"On";
    self.lightOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    //Set light two state to off
    self.lightTwoState = @"off";
    self.lightTwo.text = @"Off";
    self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    //Alloc + init instance of model class
    self.model = [[modelLight alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender {

    //check if light one is on
    if ([lightOneState  isEqual: @"on"]) {
        self.lightOne.text = [self.model turnLightOffText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightOneState = @"off";
        self.lightOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        self.lightTwo.text = [self.model turnLightOnText:self.lightTwo.text];
        self.lightTwoState = @"on";
        self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    //if light one is off
    else {
        //turn light one on
        self.lightOne.text = [self.model turnLightOnText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightOneState = @"on";
        self.lightOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        //turn light two off
        self.lightTwo.text = [self.model turnLightOffText:self.lightTwo.text];
        self.lightTwoState = @"off";
        self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
}

- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender {

    //check if light two is on
    if ([lightTwoState  isEqual: @"on"]) {

        //turn light two off
        self.lightTwo.text = [self.model turnLightOffText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightTwoState = @"off";
        self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        //turn light one on
        self.lightOne.text = [self.model turnLightOnText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightOneState = @"on";
        self.lightOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    //if light two is off
    else {

        //turn light two on
        self.lightTwo.text = [self.model turnLightOnText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightTwoState = @"on";
        self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        //turn light one off
        self.lightOne.text = [self.model turnLightOffText:self.lightOne.text];
        self.lightOneState = @"off";
        self.lightTwo.text = @"On";

    return text;
}


@end
```

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -1):

regarding initializing your model, sometimes you can init your model with [[alloc]init], pass make initWith params or static factory method it depends on the use case, if your model must have initial values it will be more correct to use factory method instead of init.

your class **modelLight** name should start with capital M **ModelLight** .

starting from xcode 4.4 you don't have to synthesize properties

```
 @synthesize lightOne, lightTwo, lightOneState, lightTwoState;
```

for representation of on/off states would be more correct to use BOOL values, like this:

where YES - the light is on and NO - the light is off.

```
 @property (strong, assing) BOOL iSlightOneOn;
 @property (strong, assing) BOOL isLightTwoOn;
```

it will make your code more readable in your if statement

please see this nice article about architecture patterns:
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.y38gl34dz

Comment: A view controller is very definitely *not* a view. And MVC is pervasive through iOS and MacOS -- if you feel that it's "very poor" you may be misunderstanding it, or perhaps you haven't expressed your concern clearly. The whole point of MVC is to decouple the view from the model and vice versa.

Comment: I know what  MVC is and I know how does it work in iOS and OSX, when I say UIViewController is view, It's not because I don't know to distinguish the controller form the view, its because in Cocoa there is no decoupling between them, if the view controller holds reference to  model and to the view it is not decoupling.I really suggest you to read the article I posted in my answer, its very interesting and useful.

Comment: the fact that the controller and the view are coupled together makes it really hard to write unit tests

Comment: It's quite unhelpful to tell someone who's obviously new at this that a view controller is a view. Regardless of whether you're right or wrong in terms of application architecture, any novice will understand you to mean that `UIViewController` is a subclass of `UIView`, which is clearly not the case. There are many opinions regarding application architectures, and many implementations of just MVC that differ from the interpretation Apple uses. That's all fine, but it's very difficult to understand that stuff until you get your feet on the ground. Injecting that here is a disservice to the OP.

Answer (score -1):

> I am embarrassed to admit it has taken me quite a while to grasp that model in MVC is just another class you reference for the data and logic an app needs (I hope that's right).

That's nothing to be embarrassed about, and you've got it about right.

> Am I right to alloc and init the model instance in the view did load, and set the properties there?

Sure, that's okay if your app only uses one view controller. Part of the advantage that you get by separating the model and the view controller is that several view controllers can all share a single data model. People often wonder how they should pass data from one view controller to another, and the answer is basically that they shouldn't -- any data that needs to be shared between controllers is data that should be in the model. Then the only thing that needs to be passed around is the model (or an appropriate part of the model).

So, since the model is often shared between view controllers, it's common to instantiate it in the app delegate, but you can also instantiate it in the first view controller that your app uses. Do whichever works best for you and lets you share it easily with other controllers.

> Have I used self properly - is it needed for all references to controller properties?

Yes. But make sure you understand what `self` is, i.e. a pointer to the object executing the code in which your use of `self` appears. When you want to send a message to an object, you need a reference to that object. When you want to use a property `foo` of an object, you send that object a `foo` (or `setFoo:`) message. If an object wants to access one of it's own properties, it sends itself one of those messages, and `self` is just how an object refers to itself.

> Any feedback also greatly appreciated.

Your view controller contains a lot of repetitive code that's really business logic. Consider this from `-button1Pressed:`:

```
if ([lightOneState  isEqual: @"on"]) {
    self.lightOne.text = [self.model turnLightOffText:self.lightOne.text];
    self.lightOneState = @"off";
    self.lightOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.lightTwo.text = [self.model turnLightOnText:self.lightTwo.text];
    self.lightTwoState = @"on";
    self.lightTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Here you're managing the states of the parts of your app, including the model, according to what button was pressed. I think you'll find it a lot easier if you separate these functions:

1. Use the user's input to update the state of the model.
2. Use the model's state to update your views.

So, when the user taps some button, all you need to do is to update the model, and then call some general method that updates the UI according to the model's state, like:

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(UIButton*)sender {
  [self.model toggleLight:1];
  [self updateLights];
  }
- (void)updateLights {
  self.light1State = self.model.light1.state;
  self.light2State = self.model.light2.state;
  // etc.
  }

Put the logic for when to turn lights on or off in the model class, not the view controller.